# How to seperate coloured boxes from the main box

Tags: python, opencv

Here is the main input image(named 1.png)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ga5sP89jttP4pWhdnBet9l_bwYxC97f5

Now, I want to identify which box is filled with color and which box is empty,
in the center big box and not the 20 side boxes that have number.

I wrote the code to extract main big box from image

```
image = cv2.imread(path)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image , cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edge = cv2.Canny(gray.copy() , 10 ,70)

_,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(edge.copy() , cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(image, contours , -1, (0,0,255) , 3)
plt.imshow(image)
cv2.imwrite('image.jpg',image)
```

Now the image looks like this

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bbqUac1Da2gLuMLly_tTAKPdkutQ5jJ-

Then I sorted the contours to get main matrix box which has all the colored and non colored boxes.

```
sorted_contours = sorted(contours,key = cv2.contourArea,reverse=True)
```

Then I seperated the main box

```
img = cv2.imread('1.png')
cnt = sorted_contours[0]
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
main_box = img[y:y+h,x:x+w].copy()
cv2.imwrite('main_box.jpg',main_box)
plt.imshow(main_box)
```

The main box looks like this:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iEhLxBkENWyam0CVFTPx-IbmNOl843MN

Mark the exterior box

```
main_box_gray = cv2.cvtColor(main_box,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, main_box_gray = cv2.threshold(main_box_gray,5,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


_,t_c,_ = cv2.findContours(main_box_gray.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

colored_main_box = img[y:y+h,x:x+w].copy()

cv2.drawContours(colored_main_box,t_c,-1,(255,0,0),2)
```

The outer box is marked,now I separated the outer contour to get boxes inside:

```
sorted_box = sorted(t_c,key = cv2.contourArea,reverse=True)

colored_main_box = img[y:y+h,x:x+w].copy()
cnt = sorted_box[0]

x2,y2,w2,h2 = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

temp_image = colored_main_box[y2:y2+h2,x2:x2+w2].copy()


edge_temp = cv2.Canny(temp_image,100,200)

_,t_c_1,_ = cv2.findContours(edge_temp.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

colored_main_box = img[y:y+h,x:x+w].copy()

colored_main_box = colored_main_box[y2:y2+h2,x2:x2+w2].copy()

cv2.drawContours(colored_main_box,t_c_1,-1,(0,0,255),1)

plt.imshow(colored_main_box)
cv2.imwrite("full_marked.jpg",colored_main_box)
```

colored_main_box(Full marked ):

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lGKXlc_7g9kYWSWfXnfYIZQZonNygKer

Now I have marked all inner boxes and i can find which box are filled by using  cv2.countNonZero funtion, but my main task is to save color inside the filled box as a separate image without the exterior black border of the box that contains that color fill, and the saved image that contain only color fill,
should be named after the box that it was extracted.

Eg: in main_box image:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iEhLxBkENWyam0CVFTPx-IbmNOl843MN

The orange color should be saved as  8.jpg

The Red color should be saved as 12.jpg

The green color should be saved as 18.jpg

The yellow should be saved as 19.jpg

The blue color should be number 21.jpg

Please help me with the code to extract and save the color fills inside the boxes with correct number label.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need more information in order to help.  What do you mean by "separate box from white ones" exactly?

Comment: This site is intended to help you figure out a problem with code you've posted, not to write code for you. I'd recommend reading the rules again, and [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then edit your post to fit this site's guidelines. As of now, there's not nearly enough info in your post to even get started on your problem, even if this site was a code writing service.

Comment: So will the image link be the input image? It seems a picture taken by a cell phone? You should provide the exact original image.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying get the colored boxes which are inside the main Square Boxes of Image. 
If that's the case , you can try below method .

1. As Main Boxes are square in Shape . Crop the image and save each boxes separate image .
2. Then use the findcounters to drawcounters around the shape which you need.
3. Crop the area of image as you already have counter values

Comment: How to do the first step, actually sir I am new to OpenCV please help me with code.

Comment: @Dettrax Below is the code Snippet , alter it as per your need
`area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
crop = img_Load_To_Crop[y:h + y, x:w + x]`

Here Cnt is the counter value which you can find using Finding Counters . img_Load_To_Crop: Image which you is loaded to be cropped